# Eager load in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wonder if we could eager load in model level:

```
# country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :country_days

  def country_highlights
    country_days.map { |country_day| country_day.shops }.flatten.uniq.map { |shop| shop.name }.join(", ")
  end
end

# country_day.rb
class CountryDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :country_day_shops
  has_many :shops, :through => :country_day_shops
end

# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base    
end
```

Most of the times it's difficult to use `.includes` in controller because of some polymorphic association. Is there anyway for me to eager load the method `country_highlights` at the model level, so that I don't have to add `.includes` in the controller?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How about using a callback like `after_initialize` to call your `country_highlights`? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "eager load" country_days from a model instance, but you can certainly skip loading them all together by using a `has_many through:`.  You can also skip the extra map, too.

```
# country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :country_days
  has_many :country_day_shops, through: :country_days  #EDIT: You may have to add this relationship
  has_many :shops, through: :country_day_shops #And change this one to use the new relationship above.

  def country_highlights
    shops.distinct_names.join(", ")
  end
end

# country_day.rb
class CountryDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :country_day_shops
  has_many :shops, :through => :country_day_shops
end

# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.distinct_names
    pluck("DISTINCT shops.name")  #Edit 2: You may need this instead of 'DISTINCT name' if you get an ambiguous column name error.
  end
end
```

The `has_many through:` will use a `JOIN` to load the associate shop records, in effect eager loading them, rather than loading all country_day records and then for each country_day record, loading the associated shop.

`pluck("DISTINCT name")` will return an array of all of the unique names of shops in the DB, using the DB to perform a `SELECT DISTINCT`, so it will not return duplicate records, and the `pluck` will avoid loading ActiveRecord instances when all you need is the string `name`.

Comment: Somehow the original method resulted in less queries and faster.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how that could be possible.  How did you execute it?

Comment: Assuming you had something like `country = Country.first; country.country_highlights`, it should issue an `INNER JOIN` query to load the shops.  There should be the query to load the country and then another to load the shops... only two.  If that is not happening, then something else is going on.  Maybe try adding `, source: :shops` to `has_many :shops, through: :country_days`.  The way your example is written, it should load n+1 queries.

Comment: A lot of this in the log: `Shop Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `shops`.* FROM `shops` INNER JOIN `country_day_shops` ON `shops`.`id` = `country_day_shops`.`shop_id` INNER JOIN `country_days` ON `country_day_shops`.`country_day_id` = `country_days`.`id` WHERE `country_days`.`country_id` = 1`

Comment: Oh, I think I may know what is going on.  You may need to add an extra relationship.  See if my edit above helps.

Comment: The additional queries still exist. But hey, it's alright. It's already a good headstart. Thanks.

Comment: I have a project with a similar structure, and it works without the extra queries.  I'm not sure what else could be going on... sorry I couldn't get it just right.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate your help. Actually I am separating questions so that I can get my head around this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152031/eager-load-differently-nested-polymorphic

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: Read the comments first*

You could cache the end result (the joined string or text record in your case), so you'll not have to load several levels of records just to build this result.

1) Add a `country_highlights` text column (result might be beyond string column limits)

2) Cache the `country_highlights` in your model with a callback, e.g. before every save.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :country_days

  before_save :cache_country_highlights

  private

  def cache_country_highlights
    self.country_highlights = country_days.flat_map(&:shops).uniq.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end
end
```

Caching you calculation will invoke a little overhead when saving a record, but having to load only one instead of three model records for displaying should speed up your controller actions so much that it's worth it.

Comment: Shouldn't he use the `before_save` callback in class `CountryDay`, since the value of `country_highlights` changes when `CountryDay` is saved (but not `Country`)?

Comment: What happens if country_days changes?  What happens if country_day_shops changes?  What happens if shops changes?  Caching this information seems like the wrong solution.

Comment: Good points, @SeanHill and @PaulRinto. I did assume that there's a `save` call on the country when a member is added or removed from the `country_days` association, but that might not automatically be the case. If the jobs change, some manual invalidation (i.e. forced saves on all associated countries) would be required. Reading the answer today, it indeed feels pretty brittle :-D. Thanks for your comments!