# Eager load differently nested polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. My models are nested in such a way:

- Review => Reviewable (Country or Shop)
- Country => CountryDay => Shop => Photos
- Shop => Photos

I have the following:

```
@reviews = @user.reviews.includes(:user, :reviewable)
```

Usually we can include nested polymorphic in such a way:

```
# this will return errors because :shop is not found in the model Shop (:reviewable is actually :shop)
@reviews = @user.reviews.includes(:user, :reviewable => [:shop])

# this will return errors because :photos is not directly associated to Country
@reviews = @user.reviews.includes(:user, :reviewable => :photos)
```

There are many other variants. How do I work around it to have the ActiveRecord includes the correct model based on its association?

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem just now. I got an `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError` when trying to load associations. My solution was to put together a custom join statement which I've put into a scope for easier usage.

Untested, but this may get you going:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :eagerly_loaded, -> {
    joins('
      INNER JOIN shops 
      ON (reviews.reviewable_type = "Shop" AND reviews.reviewable_id = shops.id)
      INNER JOIN countries 
      ON (reviews.reviewable_type = "Country" reviews.reviewable_id = countries.id)
    ')
  }
end
```

You then use `@user.reviews.eagerly_loaded`. Make sure to use a matching `.group()`-statement to only get the ones you need.